# Why cannot access a running Docker container in browser?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, locust

**Here is my dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /locust

RUN pip3 install locust

COPY ./ /locust/

EXPOSE 8089

CMD ["locust", "-f", "locustfile.py"]
```

**Here is the response:**

```
Starting web interface at http://0.0.0.0:8089 (accepting connections from all network interfaces)
Starting Locust 1.2.3
```

But when I try to access it in the browser - it doesn't load. I feel like I might be missing something simple, but cannot find it.

Comment: How are you running the container? Don't you need to map an external port to the internal port 8089?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it has been solved now. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This statement,

```
EXPOSE 8089
```

will only expose your port for inter-container communication, but not to the host.

For allowing host to communicate on the container port you will need to bind the port of host and container in the docker run command as follows

```
docker run -p <HOST_PORT>:<CONTAINER:PORT> IMAGE_NAME
```

which in your case will be

```
docker run -p 8089:8089 IMAGE_NAME
```